# Android App Crash. Error reading input stream

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, buffer-overflow

Android application crashing often, Following are the logs from logcat.

> com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from
>   input stream
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
>        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
>       Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error
>   code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
>        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
>        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)

**Any answers are highly appericiated.**

Explanation for the below error would be appreciated.

```
Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
```

Comment: paste the code so that we can have a look

Comment: It happens when your file needs more space than your buffer is actually providing

Comment: I have a similar problem, where I can see the buffer size?

Answer (score 12):

Check if you have any other android studio windows or IDE with different app is open. Sometimes android studio will throw this error when logs are running in another android studio window.

- Close the other IDE.
- restart the emulator or the device connected to check the original log.

Answer (score 0):

I rollbacked "Google" application to 10.97.8.21.

That stopped the error.