# Sending post request with Volley in Android

Tags: java, android

I need to send a post request to http://localhost:8080/login
But, I need to add two more parameters to look like this: http://localhost:8080/login/user/pass
example:
http://localhost:8080/login/hello/world
Can anyone help me please? Thank you.
Code is bellow:

```
 // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                String url ="http://localhost:8080/login";
                // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                                System.out.println("USPESNO");
                                try {
                                    JSONObject objresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                    System.out.println(objresponse);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println("NEUSPESNO");
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Pogresni podaci",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        params.put("/",username);
                        params.put("/",password);
                        return params;

                    }
                };
                // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                queue.add(stringRequest);
```

**

- LOGCAT

  ```
   2021-07-08 12:59:25.797 4273-28654/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
       com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.microdetection.d.k.a(SourceFile:91)
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.microdetection.d.l.run(Unknown Source:14)
           at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.a.b(SourceFile:32)
           at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.c.call(Unknown Source:4)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
        Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.j(SourceFile:103)
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
           at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:17)
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4) 
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
  ```

Comment: `String url ="http://localhost:8080/login/hello/world";`?..

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia No, I need to take user data from edit text in android, and to send that data to url :)

Comment: then you just need to concatenate the strings?..

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia tryed, but not working.

Comment: `String url ="http://localhost:8080/login"+edittextString+edittextstring;`

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Not working :(

Comment: why is it not working use `/` before edittextString

Comment: or check your url in log

Comment: after adding params use logcat and check your url

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Url is okay, i checked it, but it always goes to onErrorResponse method.

Comment: @NikolaStankovic What do you mean by "not working"? Be more specific and post the logcat if you're getting any errors. @UsamaAltaf Edit your comments instead of spamming... You can edit your comments within a specific amount of time (probably 1 minute or so). Also, since the OP is using `POST` method, there is no need to concatenate the **URL**; that's for `GET` method.

Comment: post your url what you are getting in logs

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I asked the OP to post the logcat to see what errors the OP is getting since just based on the description of the problem, it's not enough to tell what the problem is.

Comment: @NikolaStankovic: According to the log added error seems different that what you have specified. Check this ref 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319816/android-app-crash-error-reading-input-stream